# Python Twitter using GoogleAppEngine BadKeyError Incorrect Padding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I'm using GoogleAppEngine to try to make a simple app that requires logging in with Twitter. My problem is that when I redirect the user to some type of "confirmation" page- /profile in my case- I'm getting a badkey error because I saved the users authentication data into my db.Model.

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import urlparse
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer_key='MY_CONSUMER_KEY' 
consumer_secret='SECRET_KEY'
request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'

consumer=oauth.Consumer(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

screenname = ''

class Profile(db.Model):
  twitter_id = db.StringProperty()
  access_token = db.StringProperty()
  access_token_secret = db.StringProperty()
  twitter_user_name = db.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.out.write(template.render("login.html", {}))


class SignInWithTwitter(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
      self.request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

      self.redirect((authorize_url +'?oauth_token='+ self.request_token['oauth_token']))

class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      logging.info("tst" + screenname)
      self.profile = Profile.get(screenname)
      self.response.out.write("<h1> Hello " + self.profile.screenname +"<h1>")

class AuthorizeTwitter(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      oauth_verifier = self.request.get("oauth_verifier")
      token = oauth.Token(self.request.get('oauth_token'), self.request.get('oauth_token_secret'))
      token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
      client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
      resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
      access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
      oauth_token = access_token['oauth_token']
      oauth_token_secret = access_token['oauth_token_secret']
      userid = access_token['user_id']
      global screenname
      screenname = access_token['screen_name']

      logging.info(screenname)

      profile = Profile.get_by_key_name(screenname)
      if profile is None:
        profile = Profile(key_name = screenname)

      profile.twitter_id = userid
      profile.access_token = oauth_token
      profile.access_token_secret = oauth_token_secret
      profile.twitter_user_name = screenname
      profile.save()
      self.redirect("/profile")

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/signin', SignInWithTwitter),
    ('/services/twitter/authorized', AuthorizeTwitter),
    ('/profile', ProfilePage),
], debug=True)
```

login.html is simply a button that redirects you to /signin

The error I'm getting is this:

```
BadKeyError: Invalid string key TwitterUserNameHere===. Details: Incorrect padding
```

Also is there a way I can get the current profile that is logged in once I redirect my user to /profile? Or will I need to keep accessing my database using my global screenname variable

**EDIT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
        rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
        rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
        return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
        return handler.dispatch()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
        return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~howaggieru/1.371718316886323623/main.py", line 56, in get
        self.profile = Profile.get(screenname)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1238, in get
        results = get(keys, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1533, in get
        return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1492, in get_async
        keys, multiple = datastore.NormalizeAndTypeCheckKeys(keys)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 178, in NormalizeAndTypeCheckKeys
        keys = [_GetCompleteKeyOrError(key) for key in keys]
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2782, in _GetCompleteKeyOrError
        key = Key(arg)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 371, in __init__
        'Invalid string key %s. Details: %s' % (encoded, e))
    BadKeyError: Invalid string key TwitterUsername===. Details: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback, which shows where that error is being raised? (And not related to your error, but you *definitely* do not want `screenname` to be a global.)

Comment: I've added the whole traceback. How can I go about about doing this without making screenname global

Answer (score 0):

The traceback shows that your error is happening in `ProfilePage`. Now, in `AuthorizeTwitter` you are correctly doing  `profile = Profile.get_by_key_name(screenname)` - but in `ProfilePage` you do `profile = Profile.get(screenname)`. That assumes that "screenname" is the entire string key, which it isn't, hence the error. Use `get_by_keyname` there too.

Saving the screenname as a module-level global will lead you into all sorts of problems once you have more than one user at a time. Instead you should pass it around as a URL parameter: you're redirecting from the authorize handler to the profile one, so you should pass the twitter handle as a URL parameter to the profile function. The webapp2 docs show how to do that.